# Setting up 2 or more Repositories?

Tags: android, git, repository

My question is: can i have 2 repositories without losing my original repository.

Lets say i want the the eclair source repository

> repo init -u
>   git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git
>   -b eclair

(already synced and working)

and i would also like to sync with cyanogens repository

> repo init -u
>   git://github.com/cyanogen/android.git
>   -b eclair

All i basically want to do is have both repositories without altering or messing up the original.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`repo` works in the directory it is run. I would suggest keeping the repositories in separate places, as `repo` isn't smart enough to track two different trees in this way.

Comment: so have the original android
 

and another folder called cyanogen. would that work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally sure I understand the goal here, but it seems like all you need to do is add remotes to the repo you're working on. From your local copy:

```
git remote add android git://android.git.kernel.org/platform/manifest.git # adds the "android remote"

git remote add cyanogen git://github.com/cyanogen/android.git #adds the cyanogen remote
```

When you've made local changes and want to push them up to android, then:

```
git push android eclair #pushes to the android remote, eclair branch
```

And likewise, to the cyanogen remote:

```
git push cyanogen eclair #cyanogen remote, eclair branch
```

You can also pull from these remotes and keep the three repos fairly in sync with one another.